# Relative comparison expression

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

In my shell-script to gather CPU utilisation:

```
cpu=$(mpstat | awk '$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { print 100 - $12}');
echo "CPU Usage (%): $cpu"
```

**Output:** `CPU Usage (%): 0.44%`

This snippet follows the above two statements in my script:

```
if [ ( $cpu >= 50|bc ) -ne 0 ]; then
   /usr/sbin/sendmail "$recipients" <<EOF
   subject: $subject
   from: $from
   `date`: CPU Utilisation above 50% on $IP
EOF
echo "Mail alert triggered."
fi
```

The issue seems to be syntax related in the statement where >= comparison is being done.

Error:

```
./trialByCombat.sh: line 148: syntax error near unexpected token `$cpu'
./trialByCombat.sh: line 148: `if [ ( $cpu >= 50|bc ) -ne 0 ]; then'
```

I have no clue on this. Spaces, indentation, shell-script beats me.

Comment: Looking at it, I must be. `$cpu >= 50` alone makes no sense since it isn't within a test construct.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using BASH you can use `((...))` for arithmetic and avoid invoking `bc`:

```
if (( cpu >= 50 )); then
   /usr/sbin/sendmail "$recipients" <<EOF
   subject: $subject
   from: $from
   `date`: CPU Utilisation above 50% on $IP
EOF
echo "Mail alert triggered."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the script to:

```
if [ $(bc <<< "$cpu <= 50") -eq 1 ]
then
   /usr/sbin/sendmail "$recipients" <<EOF
   subject: $subject
   from: $from
   `date`: CPU Utilisation above 50% on $IP
EOF
echo "Mail alert triggered."
fi
```

Another sample:

```
AMD$ cat Script.sh
#!/bin/bash

cpu=49.9
if [ $(bc <<< "$cpu <= 50") -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "1"
fi

cpu=50.0
if [ $(bc <<< "$cpu <= 50") -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "2"
fi

cpu=50.1
if [ $(bc <<< "$cpu <= 50") -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "3"
fi


AMD$ ./Script.sh
1
2
```